# Can no create new C++ class in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-sdk-tools

I am running Android Studio 2.1. I have created a new blank activity project.

I have set the proper locations of the SDK, JDK, and NDK in project configuration.

I then right clicked on the 'app' folder and hit 'create new c++ class'.

I then entered a name for it called  "SquareIt". Everything in the dialog is filled out, yet the 'OK' button is still greyed out and I can not click it.

Comment: Have you tried creating the C++ file in the correct location?  Instead of right-clicking on the 'app' folder, right click on the folder where the c++ file will live.

Comment: Perhaps you should checkout something like http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview or https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Menu Bar [View]--[Tool windows]--[Project], change this drop-down box to [Project] instead of default [Android],then you can create you c++ class without encounter the 'OK' button problem.

P.S. My android studio version is 2.3.3.

[image: Change this drop-down box to Project]

Answer (score -1):

In Android Studio, right click the module name and add a new JNI folder. (New->Folder->JNI Folder).

Then right click on the newly created folder and add your c++ file from there.